# How to interpret the learning curve of a LinearRegression for sparse data?

Tags: regression, linear, sparse

I have a dataset of shape ca.(4800, 350). Both the dataset X as well as the response y is very sparse (ca. 3500 samples with y=0). I wanted to take a look at the learning curve to estimate the bias-variance tradeoff but I have difficulties to interpret the results.

In my opinion the model mostly learns the y=0 response which then leads to a higher error if the samples with y!=0 are learned (these are the peaks). If that is the case can a over-sampling strategy (e.g. SMOTE) help?

[image: Learning curve]

EDIT: per commenter (@user2974951) request a histogram of y:

[image]

Comment: My suggestion is to weight the y=0 points to both keep them in the regression and not strongly force the regression through those points. It is a good idea to find the number of distinct y values to determine if there are any similarly over-represented data points in the regression data. For example if 90 percent of the data points have a value of 0, I personally would use a weight of (1.0 - 0.9) for those points, that is, a weight of 0.1.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thank you for the recommendation. Can I just multiply my sample vector with their weight before feeding them into the estimator or how is a weighting scheme applied correctly?

Comment: Can you show a plot of y?

Comment: No you cannot directly multiply (sadly) and you would need software that allows weighted fitting. The same thing can be done by averaging the values where y = 0 into a single data point, and in this specific case that should be as effective as my weighting suggestion.

Comment: @user2974951 do you mean a histogram? (added one to the original post)

Comment: @JamesPhillips scikit-learns LinearRegression does allow fitting with sample weights. I will try that out first.

Comment: @JonasMickel Given your bounded, highly asymmetric data, a regular linear model may not be appropriate. Also, what is your first plot showing exactly, what is the x-axis? How many other variables do you have?

Comment: @user2974951 The first plot is a typical learning curve. The y-axis shows the MSE and the x-axis are the number of training samples.
What would you suggest instead of a linear model?

Comment: Your hypothesis may be true, the jumps may be because of the sudden introduction of non-zero y values as you increase you sample. But why are you looking at this plot anyway? What do you want to accomplish here? What is the end goal?

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post the learning curve can give an estimate whether the model sufferes from bias or variance error. If both the training- and cv-score converge to the same low value it means that the current dataset contains most of the variance of the experiment and increasing the sample size won't lead to better performance. If they stay around a high value and training error is worse then CV-error it is likely that the model could benefit from more data.